# Модальное окно Remodal

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как открыть модальное окно поверх уже открытого окна?
[link text](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#readme)

Answer (score 1):

```
z-index
```

Пара пара пам

Comment: Остроумно, но неверно.
При открытии второго окна первое закрывается, а не остается